# How to restrict certain paths in NetworkX graphs?

Tags: python, routes, path-finding, networkx

I am trying to calculate shortest path between 2 points using Dijkstra and A Star algorithms (in a directed NetworkX graph).

At the moment it works fine and I can see the calculated path but I would like to find a way of **restricting** certain **paths**.

For example if we have following nodes:

nodes = [1,2,3,4]

With these edges:

edges = ( (1,2),(2,3),(3,4) )

Is there a way of blocking/restricting  **1 -> 2 -> 3** but still **allow 2 -> 3 & 1 -> 2**.

This would mean that:

- **can** travel from 1 to 2
- **can** travel from 2 to 3
- **cannot** travel from 1 to 3 .. directly or indirectly (i.e. restrict 1->2->3 path).

Can this be achieved in NetworkX.. if not is there another graph library in Python that would allow this ?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if this can be done within NetworkX, but a (conceptually) simple approach would be to watch node 1 and if it is used, delete node 3 entirely.

Comment: how about https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/index.html#module-networkx.classes.graphviews  with `subgraph_view` or `restricted_view`

Answer (score 4):

Interesting question, I never heard of this problem, probably because I don't have much background in this topic, nor much experience with NetworkX. However, I do have a idea for a algorithm. This may just be the most naive way to do this and I'd be glad to hear of a cleverer algorithm.

The idea is that you can use your restriction rules to transform you graph to a new graph where all edges are valid, using the following algorithm.

The restriction of path (1,2,3) can be split in two rules:

- If you came over (1,2) then remove (2,3)
- If you leave over (2,3) then remove (1,2)

To put this in the graph you can insert copies of node 2 for each case. I'll call the new nodes **1_2** and **2_3** after the valid edge in the respective case. For both nodes, you copy all incoming and outgoing edges minus the restricted edge.

For example:

```
Nodes = [1,2,3,4]
Edges = [(1,2),(2,3),(4,2)]
```

The valid path shall only be 4->2->3 not 1->2->3. So we expand the graph:

```
Nodes = [1,1_2,2_3,3,4] # insert the two states of 2
Edges = [ # first case: no (1_2,3) because of the restriction 
          (1,1_2), (4, 1_2)
          # 2nd case, no (1,2_3)
          (2_3,3), (4,2_3)]
```

The only valid path in this graph is 4->2_3->3. This simply maps to 4->2->3 in the original graph.

I hope this answer can at least help you if you find no existing solution. Longer restriction rules would blow up the graph with a exponentially growing number of state nodes, so either this algorithm is too simple, or the problem is hard ;-)

Comment: Looks very slick to me, but i am not sure i completely understand your approach.  So is it like, 1_2 and any_2 has all the incoming/outgoing edges as 2 had, except that 1_2 wont have 1_2->3, and any_2 wont have 1->any_2?   I am asking this because there seems to be some unsymmetry between treatment of  two edges 1->2 and 2->3.

Comment: Another thing I am wondering is that the problem does not allow 1->2->3 not only directly but also **indirectly**.  In your setup, how the path like 1->2->5->6->7->3->4 is prohibited, to find path from 1 to 4?  This path includes 1->2->3 indirectly.

Comment: @yosukesabai: Good points, I think I fixed your first point. Regarding the 2nd comment, I interpreted the problem to only exclude that one restricted path without any intermediate nodes. I'm not sure how it would work out with intermediates.

Answer (score 3):

You could set your node data {color=['blue']} for node 1, node 2 has {color=['red','blue']} and node3 has {color=['red']}.  Then use an networkx.algorithms. astar_path() approach setting the

- heuristic is set to a function which returns a might_as_well_be_infinity when it encountered an node without the same color you are searching for
- weight=less_than_infinity.